# Unable to render custom CC from in magento 2

Tags: payment-methods, payment, magento-2.1.3, credit-card

I am trying to render the custom phtml file for credit card payment.

Below is my code,

In model file, I have assigned my block file

```
protected $_formBlockType = \Mypackage\Mytheme\Block\Form\Cc::class;
```

In block file I have given my custom PHtml file as,

```
<?php

namespace Mypackage\Mytheme\Block\Form;

class Cc extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form\Cc {
   protected $_template = 'Mypackage_Mytheme::form/cc.phtml';
}
```

But this code is not working for me.

Anyone did this kind of task? If so, Kindly help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Above code will only work only for admin create order if you want to render payment method in frontend you can follow [this](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-payment-method/) tutorial for getting payment method in frontend.

In Magento2 payment method are rendered using ui component in frontend.